# Laptop only reports 1gb when i installed 2gb on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have just installed windows 7 onto my laptop. I put 2 x new 1gb ddr2 modules into it. Only 1 gb is being reported by windows. Any one got any ideas? Should I try and flash the bios with new version?

I checked both the memory sticks 1 after another and they are both fine, brand new corsairs

The laptop is Amilo pro v2030

Comment: And how much is reported during boot, before Windows starts?

Comment: just checked, during post screen it says 959M extended ram passed :s

Comment: i just found a website that said the laptop supports 2gb max, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into BIOS and see how much it reports (bet only 1G).  If so, double-check your connection.  If BIOS only see 1G, Windows is only going to see 1G.

Answer (score 0):

What did you do to check the sticks?  If you've run a memory checker once with each stick in the machine, and they're both good - then I know of 3 possible problems:

- Dead RAM slot on the motherboard
- Incompatible sticks
- Putting the sticks in the wrong slots (e.g. you may be putting them in 1 and 3, when the board wants them in 1 and 2)